# Google Storage: combine getName() and getDownloadURL()?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

With the following code, I collect a  with all the files in 'folder' in Google Storage:

```
        // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        // Create a storage reference from our storage service
        var storageRef = storage.ref();         
        
        // Create a reference under which you want to list
        var listRef = storageRef.child('folder');

        // Find all items
        listRef.listAll().then(function(result){
             result.items.forEach(function(itemRef){
                  itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
                      
                        var item = $('<a>Download: ' + url + '</a>').attr({
                             'href': url
                        }).appendTo('#fileList').wrap('<li></li>');
                      
                  });
             })
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            console.log('Uh-oh, an error occured: ' + error)
        });
```

So far so good. But how can I show the name of the file instead of the url? getDownloadURL() returns only the url as I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `itemRef` is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) type object. According to the linked API documentation, you can use its [fullPath](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#fullpath) property to get the full path of the object, or [name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#name) to get the trailing file name.

Comment: Ouch – that easy :-) ('<a>Download: ' + ItemRef.name + '</a>') works perfect! Thx!!!